# Why Dart only allows for Final variables to be initiated on an initialization list?

Tags: dart

I am starting to learn Dart and I can see that a `final` variable, contrary to many other languages, can't be assigned a value inside the constructor body itself.

Why Dart imposes this limitation?

Comment: "Contrary to many other languages" ... but comparable to others, such as C++.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking more on Java, since Dart appears to have taken a lot from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization of final fields needs to be completed before the constructor body is executed, because in the constructor body read access to `this` (and its members) is allowed.

Otherwise it would be hard to make guarantees about when it is safe to access final fields.

In other languages where in the constructor body write access to final fields is allowed, it is possible to write object initialization code with unexpected behavior, for example where a final field is read before it was initialized. Dart protects you from doing that.

Comment: that's interesting.  It sounds like the constructor is called after the instance(this) is created.

Comment: Hi @SunggukLim yes that's the case. When the constructor body is executed object initilization is already completed. This allows you to do anything in a constructor body that you could do in a method (except returning a value).